# How to keep only a specific date pattern within a string in SAS?

Tags: sas

I have a text string that contains words, numbers, and dates (in mm/dd/yy format) and want to keep only the date values.

So far, using the `compress` function I'm able to keep all the numbers and "/" characters:

```
data _null_;
    string = 'text 2342 12/11/15 text 54 11/01/14 49 text 10/23/16 423';
    parsed = compress(string, '0123456789/ ', 'k');
    put parsed;
run;
```

Which returns:
`12/11/15  54 11/01/14 49  10/23/16 423`

What I want is: `12/11/15 11/01/14 10/23/16`

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I've been trying to learn PERL regular expressions expressions lately, and this is close as I can get. `pattern = prxparse('s|(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d)|TEST|') ; test = prxchange(pattern, -1, date);`. This will replace all of the dates with the word `TEST`, but we want to do the exact opposite. I haven't figured out how to negate the pattern. I'm trying to create an expression that says "If it's *not* this exact date pattern, replace it with a space."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Adapted from SAS' documentation on CALL PRXNEXT Routine)

```
data dates(keep = Text Dates);
   ExpressionID = prxparse('/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}/');
   text = 'text 2342 12/11/15 text 54 11/01/14 49 text 10/23/16 423';
   length Dates $ 120;
   start = 1;
   stop = length(text);
      /* Use PRXNEXT to find the first instance of the pattern, */
      /* then use DO WHILE to find all further instances.       */
      /* PRXNEXT changes the start parameter so that searching  */
      /* begins again after the last match.                     */
   call prxnext(ExpressionID, start, stop, text, position, length);
      do while (position > 0);
         found = substr(text, position, length);
         put found= position= length=;
         Dates = catx(" ", dates, found);
         call prxnext(ExpressionID, start, stop, text, position, length);
      end;
run;
```

Resulting dataset:

[image: resulting dataset]